# Force keras to evaluate

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am taking the cifar10_cnn.py and modifying it so I can generate my own kernels. (Trying a new idea). My code sets up the Sequential as usual, and compiles the model, then generates the CNN kernels with explicit python code, and copies them into the model. Next I call model.predict on a single image and that works fine.
Like...

```
print('layer_conv2d_2')
for img in x_train:
    print('Image %d of %d' % (imgn, x_train.shape[0]))
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    # t1 is (32,32)
    t1: tf.Tensor = layer_conv2d_1.output[0,:,:,0]
    prt = keras.backend.print_tensor(t1, 'T1 is ')
    a = model.predict(img)
    t2: tf.Tensor = layer_conv2d_1.output[0,:,:,0]
    prt = keras.backend.print_tensor (t2, 'T2 is ')
    pass
```

The print_tensor never happens.  There is a note in the docs that the return value of print_tensor must be 'used' later to get the print_tensor to be executed in the computation graph. I tried putting n = prt[0,0] and that does nothing, probably because n is never used.

How can I force a variable to get 'used'?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realize after much study and general work with Tensorflow that this question is in effect trying to force Tensorflow into a procedural paradigm. One needs to think about Tensorflow as a deferred execution graph and functional language.  It is not C++ or C# style procedural thinking.